# What does it mean for a particle to be subjected to 'more than one' simple harmonic motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, harmonics

Also what can we say now about its 
--> Resulting Energy?
-> Resulting Amplitude?
-> Maximum Velocity?

Please help as I am not able to understand the process going on.
I also tried to represent this by projection in circular motion but just couldn't.

Comment: Just add the two SHM amplitude formulas to get the total amplitude vs. time.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a little wheel spinning on the rim of a big wheel. The resulting motion of a point on the little wheel is a combination of different simple harmonic motions. Think $$x = A\sin(\omega_1 t + \phi_1) + B \sin(\omega_2 t + \phi_2)$$

Depending on the relative frequencies and phases, the max amplitude can be $A+B$; the kinetic energy is just $\frac12 m v^2$ where $v$ is the sum of the velocities.

Comment: For that matter, a particle moving in a circle is the combination of two orthogonal linear harmonic motions with sinusoidal velocity.